# How to pass context from MainActivity to another class in Android?

Tags: java, android, class, main-activity

I am experiencing an issue when trying to pass the context from the MainActivity class to another. Here is the ContextPasser Class.

```
public class ContextPasser extends Application{
public Context context;
public ContextPasser(){
    context = getApplicationContext();
}}
```

But if I use the context variable in the other class, like this:

```
Line line = new Line(new ContextPasser().context);
```

I am getting a null pointer exception. I want to get a solution which does not involve passing in a context variable because I have looked at all of the other stackoverflows and they do not seem to help me with that. One of the solutions that I found was:

```
Context context;
MyHelperClass(Context context){
this.context=context;
}
```

This does not help me because I am calling the Line class which is,

```
Line line = new Line(new ContextPasser().context);
```

in another class called the GameRunner like so:

```
public class GameRunner extends Activity {
Line line = new Line(new ContextPasser().context);
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    line.draw(canvas);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}

public void update(){
    line.update();
}
```

}

So, I want to create a method that will pass the Context without accepting parameters of the Context class themselves.

Please let me know any suggestions or answers. 
I would really appreciate it. 
Thanks a lot for your time and consideration!

Comment: activity having own context so why don't you use Line line=new Line(this);

Comment: Did my answer help you ?

Answer (score 8):

If your other class is a non-activity class this is how you pass the `Context`:

```
public class MyNonActivityClass{

// variable to hold context
private Context context;

//save the context received via constructor in a local variable

public MyNonActivityClass(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

}
```

And this is how you pass the context :

```
MyNonActivityClass mClass = new MyNonActivityClass(this);
```

Comment: be aware that this can cause a memory leak if the parent activity is destroy

Answer (score 5):

[OBX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036325/1953590) shows one way to do it.  But you should understand why your approach does not work.

Instances of Android components such as `Application` and `Activity` are not fully realized as `Context`s until they've been initialized by the framework.  This happens sometime before `onCreate(...)` is called.  If you create a `new` instance yourself, it won't be initialized and will neither have nor be usable as a `Context`.  For the same reason, calling `getApplicationContext()` in a field assignment or constructor will return `null` or throw an exception.

```
MyActivity extends Activity {
  private Context appContext = getApplicationContext(); // wrong

  public MyActivity {
    appContext = getApplicationContext(); // wrong
  }

  public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    appContext = getApplicationContext(); // correct
  }
}
```

Comment: But I think getApplicationContext() returns data provided by Android OS right? It's not like we are instantiating/initializing an Application instance by ourselves.

Comment: @Harsha Yes, but that data isn't there until the framework has initialized the activity instance.  Check out the source for [`ContextWrapper`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java), which `Activity` indirectly extends. A lot of methods won't work until `mBase` is set.

Comment: Alright, I get it now.. So if this activity here is not the first activity, is it then valid to initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: @Harsha No. Calling `getApplicationContext()` in an activity's constructor or field initializer will always result in an NPE.