# Cant find a simple way to vibrate the phone (source code android)

Tags: android

```
Context mcontext;
this.Context= mcontext;
//private Context context;
//this.context=context;
//super(mcontext);
Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
mVibrator.vibrate(300)
```

I searched online a lot for simple code to play a beep and I found one. But I am unable to add and compile few line of code to make the phone vibrate. All the threads I have come across uses getsystemservice(). 
[Link to some code to vibrate on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate)

First `getsystemservice()` function alone does not work and somewhere I read it needs to be called by a `context object`. I made a context object. Then it says context needs to be initialized. I tried `this.context = context` and that gives another error. I am getting into these cycle of compilation errors for what should be a simple job to just vibrate the phone. Please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

This question is different as I took the experience from other threads. As other threads give answer to use getsystemservice() alone but that does not work because it needs a context.

Update: came across this thread here [How to pass context from MainActivity to another class in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036278/how-to-pass-context-from-mainactivity-to-another-class-in-android)

So I did this

```
public class MyNonActivityClass{

// variable to hold context
private Context context;

//save the context received via constructor in a local variable

public MyNonActivityClass(Context context){
this.context=context;
}

}
```

But then I get error mcallback might not have been initialized here.

```
private final Callback mCallback;
```

And then where do I add this

```
MyNonActivityClass mClass = new MyNonActivityClass(this);
```

Comment: you need to add permission in manifest file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
and add Bellow Code it think it should work
// Vibrate for 150 milliseconds
private void shakeItBaby() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(150, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
    } else {
        ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(150);
    }
}

Comment: I did add the permission to vibrate in androidmanifest.xml

Comment: Where are u calling it from?

Comment: You seem to lack basic knowledge. It's better to go slow and do some tutorials to learn instead of rushing to make something you don't understand

Comment: I took some basic source code and put my code into that. The app is working well I just need to add the vibration of the phone...thats it,,,

Answer (score 1):

From where you are calling the `Vibrator service` ?

If its from activity then,

```
Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    mVibrator.vibrate(300)
```

or if its from Frgament then,

```
 Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    mVibrator.vibrate(300)
```

or update this in your code like,

```
void vibrate(Context mcontext ){
    Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) 
    mcontext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    mVibrator.vibrate(300)
}
```

Comment: this.getsystem... does not work as this gets highlighted in red. getActivity also does not work..I am trying to beep from a user define class not in mainactivity.java. Pardon my little knowledge as my android programming experience is limited. Problem is getsystemservice is not getting resolved.

Comment: Then you need to pass the context form MainActivity to the user define class. See my updated answer.

Comment: So can I not assign it the context in the user defined class. Or if I have to pass it from mainactivity.java then how shall I do it because I am using this to indicate the end of a recording activity in a recording thread. The main thread will not know what is happening in this thread. So can I not take a context itself from the class which it is defined in? Is it the only way. Can I not use view.getcontext or activity.getapplicationactivity or something like that?

Comment: I am creating an object for a class private VoiceRecorder mVoiceRecorder; And the record function defined in the class voice recorder which is running a thread runnable->record( ). Now specifically how do I manage context here....?

Comment: I updated my issue further.